# TensorFlow Error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to Python and machine learning.  I am getting an error whenever I run the following code:

```
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():  
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))  
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)  
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs) 
    return ds  
  return input_function  


train_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_train, y_train)  
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_test, y_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)

linear_est.train(train_input_fn) 
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn) 

clear_output() 
print(result['accuracy'])
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-47fb35491976> in <module>()
----> 1 linear_est.train(train_input_fn)
      2 result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
      3 
      4 clear_output()
      5 print(result['accuracy'])

5 frames
<ipython-input-36-16cfc32eb7b2> in input_function()
      1 def make_input_fn(X_train, y_train, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
      2   def input_function():
----> 3     ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X_train), y_train))
      4     if shuffle:
      5       ds = ds.shuffle(1000)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

I am not sure if the issue would be related to my data or data types. My data has no blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of your creating a dictionary in improper format.

For example:

```
t1 = ('a','b','c','d')
t2 = (1,2,3,4)
dict(t1) #output: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
dict(zip(t1,t2)) #output: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

By creating a dictionary using the `dict` function with proper format will not produce that error. Thank You!